# How to connect expo go app through docker devcontainer

Tags: docker, macos, expo, vscode-devcontainer

#### problem

cannot connect with my expo app to the expo simulation

#### setup

- set up a devcontainer with vscode's extension.
- login into my expo account
- successful build
- expo go and laptop in the same network
- has worked before with last linux pc
- `node -e 'console.log(os.networkInterfaces())'` results:

```
{
  lo: [
    {
      address: '127.0.0.1',
      netmask: '255.0.0.0',
      internal: true,
      cidr: '127.0.0.1/8', 
      ...
    }
  ],
  eth0: [
    {
      address: '172.17.0.3',
      netmask: '255.255.0.0',
      internal: false,
      cidr: '172.17.0.3/16',
      ...
    }
  ]
```

#### I tried

- setting REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME to host's ip

  - without it gives me a link from its eth0
- open mac's firewall to vscode and docker
- turn off mac's firewall
- switch to tunnel connection

  - *but this gives an error for another question later*
- tried posting and currently waiting responses [here](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/4307) while exercising my google-fu

#### my environment

mac os 12.3 (monterey)
docker 4.7.1
devcontainer from microsoft's nodejs (alpine with node)
expo cli version: v5.3.2

#### previous environment

ubuntu 21.04
docker ~4.7.1
devcontainer from microsoft's nodejs (alpine with node)
expo cli version: ~5.3.2

#### to reproduce

1. setup a devcontainer

   - `"VARIANT": "14-bullseye"`
   - `"features": {"git": "latest","aws-cli": "latest","desktop-lite": "latest","python": "latest" }`
2. `npm i -g expo-cli`
3. `expo init` a new sample project
4. `expo start`
5. try to connect expo go via the qr

   1. no errors on expo-cli but go-app `java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /192.x.x.x:19000`
6. if not working like me:

   1. close expo
   2. `export REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.xxx` xxx is host's lan ip address
   3. `expo start`
   4. try connecting with expo go app via qr

      1. no errors on expo-cli but go-app `java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /192.x.x.x:19000`

Comment: now i'm looking for some kind of solution with docker nat and docker port mapping

Comment: Rather than abstractly describing the problem, can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], as the actual code and commands you're running and the actual error message you're getting?

Comment: included steps to reproduce